# Custom post type paging 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

I've an issue on custom post type, 
I've create a custom post type called "Agenda" and the rewrite url for http://example.com/agenda it works correctly, it points to the archive-agenda.php template but for http://example.com/agenda/page/2 it shows 404 error,
what do you suggest me?
The code that I've used to add the custom post type is:

```
 <?php
function create_event_type() {
    $event_args = array(
        'label' => __('Agenda'),
        'singular_label' => __('Evento'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'revisions', // (will store revisions)
            //'page-attributes', // (menu order, hierarchical must be true to show Parent option)
            'title',
            'editor')
    );
    register_post_type('agenda', $event_args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_event_type');
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see you have a closing tag, just encase, this code needs to be in `functions.php` or in a plugin, placing it in a template means when the code runs it's too late

Comment: What @TomJNowell is saying is that your `add_action` function is running too late. Place it at the earliest possible place in`functions.php` or a plugin file somewhere.

Comment: Lol, I still can't operate this site. 3 year old question shows up on the top of my feed... I have no clue why. Whatever, please enjoy my banter, it is meant to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your permalinks... "powercycle them" :) click "Numeric" -> Save then back to "Post Name" and save (or vice versa)

Comment: just visiting the permalinks settings page flushes rewrite rules, no need to change anything.

Comment: Good to know @milo!

Comment: @BenRacicot I don't even know what click "Numeric" -> Save means. What is that?

Comment: @milo does  entering that page flush, or do you have to save?

Comment: People say entering the page flushes them but has never worked for me. I've always had to re-save URL format to "Numeric" then switch them back to the desired format.

Comment: Any load of the `options-permalink.php` page flushes the rewrite rules, [you can see it here on line 151 of the current version](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/options-permalink.php#L151).

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup pagination when you query your custom post something like this

`$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;`

Comment: This is the right track. Your template will have to have this code, especially if it is custom. Research in this area will get you everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the answer today. I've added a rewrite rule for a workaround.

check my answer for this question: [wrong template for page of archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166628/wrong-template-for-page-of-archive/166981)