# wrong template for page of archive

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, rewrite-rules

I am trying to add pagination to the archiveof my custom post type. Right now it is structured by year & month and I want to add pagination and I fail miserably.

So its like this:

```
<!-- Request: cpt/2014/pagina/2 -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Rule: cpt/([0-9]{4})/pagina/?([0-9]{1,})/?$ -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Query: post_type=cpt&amp;year=2014&amp;paged=2 -->
<!-- Loaded Template: index.php -->
```

And it should load `archive-cpt.php` like this:

```
<!-- Request: cpt/2014 -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Rule: cpt/([0-9]{4})/?$ -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Query: post_type=cpt&amp;year=2014 -->
<!-- Loaded Template: archive-cpt.php -->
```

For some **special** posts I have added a marker and it works. (also pagination fails here as well)

```
<!-- Request: cpt/marker -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Rule: evenimente/marker/?$ -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Query: post_type=cpt&amp;marker=yes -->
<!-- Loaded Template: archive-cpt.php -->
```

I am hooking myself into `init` and adding rules like so:

```
add_rewrite_rule( #works
    $cpt_name. '/marker/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=' . $cpt_slug . '&marker=yes',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_rule( #fails
    $cpt_name . '/marker/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=' . $cpt_slug . '&paged=$matches[1]&marker=yes',
    'top'
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because WordPress redirected to `index.php` when it should have loaded `archive.php` or `archive-cpt.php` I made a workaround like so:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    $cpt_name . '/page/?([0-9]{1,})?$',
    'index.php?post_type=' . $cpt_slug . '&qpaged=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

`qpaged` instead of `paged`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ["Template Hierarchy" Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

> ### Custom Post Type Archive display
>
> Template file used to render the Archive **Index page for a Custom Post Type**. [emphasis added]

By my reading, that means that the `archive-{cpt_slug}.php` template is only used for the page that, by default, lists all posts of that post type in reverse chronological order. I think what you're seeing, at least in terms of the template being used, is the correct expected behavior.

If you want to use a different template—either the `archive-cpt.php` file or a different specifically for your date-based queries—then you should look into [the `template_include` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) that lets you change which template WordPress uses.

Similar versions of this question have been asked already, so check those out for more help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386709/date-archives-for-custom-post-type
- [Adding a date archive to Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140292/adding-a-date-archive-to-custom-post-type)
- [custom post types, wp_get_archives and add_rewrite_rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50530/custom-post-types-wp-get-archives-and-add-rewrite-rule)

Comment: If `site.com/cpt` loads `archive-cpt.php` shouldn't `site.com/cpt/page/2` load `archive-cpt.php`?

Comment: Sure, but I think your rewrite rule to add the year is messing things up.

Comment: I will investigate further when I get to work. But those rules are paramount for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use wp pagination instead of using all kind of rewrite rules.

Just use the basic rewrite rules for WordPress. You're CPT will use archive-cpt.php as the archive.

put pagination in your template 
(http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

Job done (i.e https://medischevacature.nl/vacatures/ cpt = "vacatures")

Comment: By default CPTS dont have a year/month/day archive. That is why those rewrite rules are in place.

Comment: Use php/query them?

Comment: The question has been answered.